# How to open new tab just once using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript .I want to have a javascript code that allow to open new tab for a link just once when you click on either buttons but when you click on same button or other button , the script wont work .For example : After clicking on the download or printing button I want to open new tab of my facebook page but I want to do it just once , so if that user clicked on download button that's it .So even if he clicks on same button multiple times or other print button multiple times the facebook function wont work at all

```js
function facebook() {
  window.open("https://www.facebook.com");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="facebook();printContent('exportContent')"  >Print</button>
<button onclick="facebook();Download();" >Download</button>
```

I tried to use  `this.onclick=null` in the buttons but it cause two problems : 1/ It make other functions  just work once while I want other functions to keep working each time the buttons are clicked and facebook function to work just once ; 2/ when click on one of the buttons new tab opens and when you click on other button it still open too .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global variable to keep track of how many times you invoked **facebook** function

```js
var counter = 0;

function facebook() {
  if(counter === 0) {
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com");
    counter += 1;
  }
}

function Download() {
  console.log('dl')
}

function printContent(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="facebook();printContent('exportContent')"  >Print</button>
<button onclick="facebook();Download();" >Download</button>
```